# Why do I get this Rails error when trying to install gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

So when I try to install mysql2 I get the following error:

```
/Users/Koolkrasher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /bin in PATH, mode 040777

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Koolkrasher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.3.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Koolkrasher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

All my permissions are good: 755 all the way down from home - bin

Comment: I thought compilation warnings shouldn't affect the outcomes of compilation. Aren't there any additional error messages you that you left out?

Comment: Not sure based on what you've written. You may also want to try [#rvm on freenode](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/support/irc/) (IRC) if you don't get a response here.

Comment: It's complaining about /bin being world writable, not about /home/.../.rvm/.../bin. Are you sure the permissions for /bin are ok?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in the wrong path.  The bin dir that was world writable was(is) in my export path.
sudo chmod 755 bin did the trick.

Thanks for all the suggestions guys. much appreciated.